# HTML/Javascript: Selecting uncles/aunts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

So I have some code,

```
<div class="chunk" id="">
    <div class="chunkContent">
        <div class="textLeft" ></div>
        <div class="textRight" ></div>
        <div class="notes border">Notes...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tools fl">
        <div class="toggleNotes border">n</div>
        <div class="addChunk border">+</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the two divs nested withing div.tools are small buttons. div.toggleNotes I need to select div.notes in a javascript/jquery function. div.addChunk I need to select the fisrt div, div.chunk. Currently, I am doing this by:

```
$(".addChunk").live('click', (function(){create_chunk(this.parentNode.parentNode)}))
$(".toggleNotes").live('click',function(){toggle_notes(this.parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild.lastElementChild)})
```

Is there a better (i.e., more proper) way to do this than to string together parentNotes and firstElementChild's and etc.? I'm basically looking around the DOM tab in firebug.

Comment: why not just use ids to select them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with jQuery, I assume you're open to using its traversal methods. This will ensure cross-browser support.

If so, you could do this:

```
&(".addChunk").live('click', function(){
   create_chunk($(this).closest('.chunk')); // Get closest ancestor with class 'chunk'
});

$(".toggleNotes").live('click',function(){
   toggle_notes($(this).parent().prev().find('.notes'));  // Get parent element, traverse
});                                                       //  to its previous sibling,
                                                          //  and find element with 'notes'
```

---

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, if you wanted, you could use `.closest()` for `toggle_notes` as well.

```
$(".toggleNotes").live('click',function(){
   toggle_notes($(this).closest('.chunk').find('.notes'));
});
```

---

**Relevant jQuery docs:**

- `.closest()` - http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- `.parent()` - http://api.jquery.com/parent/
- `.prev()` - http://api.jquery.com/prev/
- `.find()` - http://api.jquery.com/find/
- jQuery traversal methods - http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
$("div:.addChunk").live('click', function() {
    create_chunk($(this).parent().parent());
});

$("div:.toggleNotes").live('click',function() {
    toggle_notes($(this).parent().siblings('div:.chunkContent').find('div:.notes'));
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) selector for this, but it does seem as if you could use classes or ids to accomplish this in a less complicated way.